# Connecting to Tabular Server in "Analysis Services Connector"

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular, powerbi

I have a SSAS Tabular on a Windows Server hosted on AWS. The Tabular service port number is 53399. It is up and running fine.
To connect to it, I am trying to configure Power BI Analysis Services Connector installed on my laptop at office by entering server IP address and my Windows server credentials but getting "The server you're trying to connect to cannot be found.".
I tried , :53399, ,53399 in "Analysis Services Server" section of the connector but nothing works. The firewall is Ok. I can telnet from my laptop to the server using the same port number.

Any idea what can be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Note that one connector must be installed per ssas instance. There is no advantage in having a connector on your laptop if you were thinking of using it for multiple servers. So installing the connector on the AWS machine would be the simplest means of achieving the cloud connectivity. See http://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/471577-configure-a-power-bi-analysis-services-connector

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to hear you're having trouble with the SSAS connector.  We'd love to help you get it resolved. Could you submit a support request here:

http://support.powerbi.com/

Click on "**Contact Support**".

Appreciate your using Power BI.

Lukasz P.

Power BI Team, Microsoft

If you'd like to stay up to date with the Power BI developer story updates you can register (http://solutions.powerbi.com/appsuggestion.html) or follow our blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/)